# Why javascript function is not running?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, html

I have created javascript function in html file, and in ajax success will console data. But there aren't showing in console, and there are not error found in console.

What happen?

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>   
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="div-form">
            <h1>form</h1>
            <fom action="#" id="ajax-form" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <label>Nama:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="nama mu">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <label>Email:</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="email mu">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <button class="btn" name="submit" type="submit" value="SUBMIT" id="contact-submit">submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $("#ajax-form").submit(function(event) {
            /* Act on the event */
            var jsondata = $("#ajax-form").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'proccess.php',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: jsondata,
            })
            .done(function() {
                console.log("success" + data);
            })
            event.preventDefault();
        });

    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` should be `event.preventDefault();` as the event parameter is called `event` not `e`

Comment: use error callback in your ajax to see if whats the error, eg. `$.ajax({url:....,error:function(msg){ console.log(msg);} } );`

Comment: or use `.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown )` ;).   Also, there is a `;` missing right after your .done().

Comment: there is a spelling mistake in the form opening tag, pls check its written as fom :)

Comment: and use event.preventDefault(); instead of e.preventDefault(); because you are passing event as param to the function not e

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that only `event` will work here is the updated Code

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#ajax-form").submit(function(event) {
        /* Act on the event */
        var jsondata = $("#ajax-form").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'proccess.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: jsondata,
        })
        .done(function() {
            console.log("success" + data);
        })
        event.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

Comment: Please upvote existing answers, rather than duplicating them :)

Comment: please check again, i have update it but still haven't showing in console

Comment: You are lie, it can be not only `event`. It just an argument. It even can be `arguments[0]`...

Answer (score 4):

The name of the event you're passing back to the `submit()` function is `event`, yet you try to call `preventDefault()` on a variable of `e`, which is actually the event passed back from the DOMReady callback. As a result, the submit event is never prevented.

You need to update as follows (notice also that we need to pass a variable of `data` back to the `done()` callback):

```
$("#ajax-form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    /* Act on the event */
    var jsondata = $("#ajax-form").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'proccess.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: jsondata,
    })
    .done(function( data ) {
        console.log("success" + data);
    });
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't `.done` receive `data` as `parameter` before this -> `console.log("success" + data);`?

Comment: Yeah, it should. I've added it to the answer, but that isn't the reason his code is 'not working'.

Comment: True but OP might raise next question if he don't find that `data`. That was my concern.. :)

Comment: i have update the code, check again. but still haven't showing in console

Comment: @Ariasa, then your AJAX request is likely returning an error. Use the error() function to check that, or see the Network tab to check what response your call gives.

Answer (score 0):

please correct the spelling mistake in the html tag

```
 <fom action="#" id="ajax-form" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">

 <form action="#" id="ajax-form" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

jQuery is not able to bind the submit event with the form element since there is no form element.